# Problem while checking internet connectivity on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, connectivity

I was trying to check the internet connection on my flutter app with the help of connectivity plus package and a function which I saw in one of the answers of stackoverflaw. Below is the code:

connectivity_check.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

enum ConnectivityStatus { Online, Offline }

class ConnectivityService {
  // Create our public controller
  StreamController<ConnectivityStatus> connectionStatusController =
      StreamController<ConnectivityStatus>();
  final _connectivity = Connectivity();
  ConnectivityService() {
    // Subscribe to the connectivity Chanaged Steam

    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      _checkStatus(result);
    });

  void _checkStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    bool isOnline = false;
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      isOnline = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
      print(isOnline);
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      isOnline = false;
    }
    if (isOnline == true)
      connectionStatusController.sink.add(ConnectivityStatus.Online);
    else
      connectionStatusController.sink.add(ConnectivityStatus.Offline);
  }

  void disposeStream() => connectionStatusController.close();
}
```

StreamProvider in main.dart

```
StreamProvider<ConnectivityStatus>(
            initialData: ConnectivityStatus.Online,
            create: (_) =>
                ConnectivityService().connectionStatusController.stream)
```

The Widget where I am using this connectivity provider

```
class OfferPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: (Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context) ==
              ConnectivityStatus.Online)
          ? ListView(
              children: [
                OfferImage(image: 'offer_banner.jpg'),
                OfferImage(image: 'offer1.jpg'),
                OfferImage(image: 'offer2.jpg'),
              ],
            )
          : Text('ok'),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem which I am facing is that the isOnline is always returning true even if I switch off my Wifi/data. Whenever stream provider listens to change in network, it returns true/Online, it doesn't return false/Offline. Can someone help and debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid _checkStatus call which used `InternetAddress.lookup`, as we already have `ConnectivityResult`, its better to use that only.

**Package(https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity/install):**

```
connectivity: ^3.0.6
```

**Connectivity.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

class ConnectivityService {
  ConnectivityService() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      connectionController.add(_getStatus(result));
    });
  }

  StreamController<ConnectivityStatus> connectionController =
      StreamController<ConnectivityStatus>();

  ConnectivityStatus _getStatus(ConnectivityResult result) {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Online;
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Online;
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Offline;
      default:
        return ConnectivityStatus.Online;
    }
  }
}

enum ConnectivityStatus { Online, Offline }
```

**Register Provider:**

```
StreamProvider<ConnectivityStatus>(
                        create: (context) => ConnectivityService().connectionController.stream),
```

**Usage:**

```
 var connectionStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);
    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.Online) {
      /// Online logic
    } else {
     /// Offline logic
    }
```

Comment: But the problem is that the Connectivity result will return Online even if we are connected with Wi-fi but not connected with internet. Hence I feel IP lookup is important.

Comment: in my case it gives for both wifi and mobile internet. @RishabhGupta: maybe you can follow the same way which I posted.